# Try statement - multiple conditions - Python 2

Tags: python

I have little problem with try statement along with multiple conditions. When there is error at 2nd condition, it asks for 1st condition. What I want from it to do is to repeat the same condition, not the whole cycle. I hope you understand me, since my English isn't very good and also I'm newbie to Python so I also don't know how to describe it in my native language.

I hope the following example will help you to better understand my thought.

```
while True:
    try:
        zacatek = float(raw_input("Zacatek: "))
        konec = float(raw_input("Konec: "))
    except Exception:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

it does following:

```
Zacatek: 1
Konec: a
Zacatek:
```

but I want it to do this:

```
Zacatek: 1
Konec: a
Konec:
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Write a function to query for a single `float`, and call it twice:

```
def input_float(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(raw_input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            pass
zacatek = input_float("Zacatek: ")
konec = input_float("Konec: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your except clause is catching a ValueError exception on your answer to Konec and returning to the top of the loop.

Your float function is trying to cast a non-numeric response "a" to a float and it throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could write a different loop for each input:

```
zacatek = None
while not zacatek:
    try:
        zacatek = float(raw_input("Zacatek: "))
    except Exception:
        continue

konec = None
while not konec:
    try:
        konec = float(raw_input("Konec: "))
    except Exception:
        continue
```

Comment: @delnan: No, it isn't.  This version will ask again if I enter '0', mine doesn't.